# Maclaurin Expansion for Cos not approximating correctly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to make a function that approximates Cos(2) using the Maclaurin series approximation. So far I've made a 'Do' loop, but my approximation is off by -1.

My Function:

```
valX = 2
result = 0
numTerms = 5
i = 0

Do[
 Print[
  SetPrecision [
   result = 
    result + (-1)^i*
      (valX^(2*i)/Factorial[2*i]), 10]], {i, numTerms}]
```

Results:

```
-2.000000000
-1.333333333
-1.422222222
-1.415873016
-1.416155203 //decimal is correct but I'm off by -1.
```

Comment: Do not vandalize this site, including posts you have made. Please revert to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Mathematica is 1-indexed, your `Do[..., {i, numTerms}]` loop ranges from 1 to numTerms. You probably want to go from 0 to numTerms. Try this, where the change is on the last line:

```
valX = 2
result = 0
numTerms = 5
i = 0

Do[
 Print[
  SetPrecision [
   result = 
    result + (-1)^i*
      (valX^(2*i)/Factorial[2*i]), 10]], {i, 0, numTerms}]
```

Comment: ah, yes thanks, that's a better solution. I didn't realise that mathematica was 1-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figured it out. What has to happen is that I have to compensate for formula being recursive by subtracting from the exponent.

Correct Formula:

```
  result =
    result + (-1)^i-1*
    (valX^(2*i-2)/Factorial[2*i-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The convergence is quicker too if you start expanding from Pi/2, i.e: valX=2-Pi/2 and the loop starts at i=1